# Wary of locked Windows 8 BIOS

Tags: boot, windows-8, bios

I've been looking for a good inexpensive laptop to purchase and throw linux on, but when I was in line to purchase one, the store rep mentioned that its BIOS was locked to Windows 8, and that Linux wouldn't install on it. Is this true of some laptops?

If so, how can I be certain that a laptop I buy has an unlocked BIOS that allows me to install linux?

Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: Thanks that helps, still a confusing process though...

Comment: Windows RT has a locked UEFI version that nothing else can be installed on. If just a full Windows 8 system with UEFI then it should be secure boot and Ubuntu has the Microsoft signing key to work even with secure boot on in UEFI. Some laptops will boot Windows with secure boot off also, some only with it on.